# Exception Handling: try-catch block error

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I tried to test the size of two strings and catch the error in try-catch block. I am getting "Cannot find symbol" error in the line containing throw statement.

```
class test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a = "abcdefghi";
        String b = "abcdefgh";

        try {
            if (a.length() != 9) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException;
            }

            if (b.length() != 10) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException;
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

[image of error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7JFY.png)

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException();`

Answer (score -1):

You need to create instances of Exceptions thrown like

```java
public static void main(String args[]){
    String a = "abcdefghi";
    String b = "abcdefgh";
    
    try{
        if(a.length()!=9){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if(b.length()!=10){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    } 
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```